# How to use AWS Simple Email Service (SES) in Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-simple-email-service, django-ses

I'm trying to use [`this library`](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses) to integrate my Django project with AWS SES.

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my_aws_access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my_aws_secret_access_key'

AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

It throws the following error

```
SESAddressNotVerifiedError: 400 Email address is not verified.
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: jpark1320@gmail.com, webmaster@localhost</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>0220c0a0-741b-11e8-a153-475b5dfc6545</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I can't even guess why is wrong on my codes. But, one thing might be a problem is `send_mail()`. I'm using trying to send an email to a user for sign-up confirmation. I put the codes for sending email below.

**SMTP settings**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_google_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_google_email_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'My Team Name <noreply@gmail.com>'
```

**Update**

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a user object to set email to be username before passing it to db
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            user.is_active = False
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = "[Modvisor] Please verify your email address."
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = user.email
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()

            return redirect('signup_confirm')

    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: The error is telling you you have put two email addresses as the sender, which doesn't make sense. Show the code that calls send_mail.

Comment: @Daniel I think `send_mail` is working well because when I tried with the SMTP setting, the mailing worked very well. I put my SMTP setting in my original post.

Comment: But I asked you to show the code that *calls* it, because you are clearly doing something wrong there.

Comment: Concerning the two emails, `jpark1320@gmail.com` is an email that I'm trying to send a confirmation email for sign-up, and I have no idea where `webmaster@localhost` comes from.

Comment: @Daniel Oops, sorry for missing that. Just updated the original post with the mailing codes!

Comment: Also, there was my mistake to say that it's about password reset, but it was actually for signup confirmation email, which means I didn't use Django built-in function. Anyways, please check the function on the updated post. I'm sorry for making confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part of the error is "Email address is not verified". By default SES is in sandbox mode where it won't let you use From or To addresses that you have not previously verified. You need to verify the addresses in the SES console or open a support request to leave sandbox.

[Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html)

To verify an address go to the SES console. On the left side select Email Addresses and then click Verify New Email Address. You will need to have access to the email address so you can click the link that will be sent to it.

[Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

To move out of the sandbox simply [open a support request](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/), describe your use case and wait a few days.

Comment: I have a question. I already verified my Google email that I wanna use to send emails for signup confirmation and password reset. Doesn't it make sense that we have new users' emails or existing users' emails? Do I have verify all of the emails so that I can send emails to them?

Comment: No, you should leave the sandbox so you don't need to verify all emails. You should also leave the sandbox so you don't have other rate limitations.

Comment: Got it, I'll follow the link you gave me to get out the sandbox. By the way, what are benefits joining in the sandbox?

Comment: It's a test mode so you don't spam too many emails by mistake while developing.

Comment: Which means that all people move out of the Sandbox at the end to use it properly. Is that correct?